# why echo in shell script can't print -n option

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

The following script can only print `-m` but it can't print `-n`.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $@
```

```
$ sh test.sh -m
-m
$ sh test.sh -n
$
```

Comment: `$@` doesn't print anything, and it deals with `-n` just fine, though you should be using `"$@"` instead; or maybe `"$*"` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `-n` is an actual option to `echo`. Most tools support `--` to mean "there's no more options after this, just arguments", so try if using

```
echo -- $@
```

improves the situation.

Comment: it doesn't, in pretty much any shell